# Class UML Diagram - quick question

Tags: uml, diagram

i have a calculator class and a main class. If i were to create a calculator object inside the main class, it would be ... "main class has a calculator" main<--calculator. However, if i call method functions calls from calculator class inside the main class, how will this look/be (since im not creating an instance of calculator, is there any relationship between these two)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main class calls a method on calculator, but doesn't create, own or keep a permanent reference to the calculator, the best way of describing the relationship between them might be "Dependency".

See the section title "Dependency" on this wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

To the right of it is a picture depicting a visual representation of "dependency" -- note the use of the word "uses" on the arrow.